# Jqueryui dialog "resizeable: false" not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Below is my code.  When it opens the modal, it IS resizeable even though it's set to false.  This is not expected.  All other parameters work as expected (height, width, position, draggable, modal).

```
    //MODAL IFRAME POPUP FOR EDITS/adds
    $("#modalDiv").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: '400',
        width: '400',
        position: ['150','200'],
        draggable: true,
        resizeable: false,
        title: ''
    });

    //catch a click on an item with the class "add" open modal div.
    $('.add').live('click', function () {
        var thing = $(this).attr('add')
        url = 'add/' + thing + '.aspx?appid=' + $('.lblAppID').html();
        $('#modalIFrame').attr('src', url);
        $('#modalDiv').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

However, if I call the following code from within the modal iframe, it makes it unresizeable (as expected).

```
window.parent.$("#modalDiv").dialog("option", "resizable", false);
```

This works, but preferably I'd like to know what I'm missing... I'm sure it's something stupid.  Help?

Comment: That's indeed `resizable`, not `resizeable`.

Comment: I love that this question has 1000 views now... wonder how many people are searching for "resizeable" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's **resizable**, not resizeable.

Comment: @Scott Beeson it certainly gets frustrating when you miss one of those things and just try and try, but nothing seems to be working :)

Comment: I'm just glad I can finally blame one of my questions on spelling and not total lack of competence.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You're spelling the word two different ways :-)